# German "für die klugen Leute" specific translation?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, vocabulary

I was just wondering about a specific translation:

> German for clever people

Would that be translated thus?

> Deutsch für die klugen Leute

And specifically about word order for adjectives and appropriate usage of vocabulary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase

> *correct:* Deutsch für die klugen Leute.

is grammatically correct. However, normally you wouldn't use the article *die* here:

> *better:* Deutsch für kluge Leute.

And even now there's still a more idiomatic phrase for *clever/smart people* which is *kluge Köpfe* (literally: *smart heads*). So my suggestion is:

> *more idiomatic:* Deutsch für kluge Köpfe.

<sup>I have no idea what *German for clever people* is. The language doesn't change with regard to intelligence, does it?</sup>

Comment: Regarding the small print: Sounds like a book title or something similar to me

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde sagen:

> Deutsch für die Schlauen